Error occured when trying to run webdriver
I have been trying to run the chromdriver using this code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Anfield\Archive\Chromedriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

url = 'https://shopee.co.th'
driver.get(url)

And always getting this error
[4124:24652:1217/120010.859:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
[9408:22992:1217/120011.263:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(331)] GPU state invalid after WaitForGetOffsetInRange.

The chromedriver will only appear for a moment before it gone. Does anybody know what the trouble may be?
I have been searching online by placing the state of an error in the search box but so far I haven't been able to find the right solution.

The error is related to WebRTC and GPU acceleration and can be resolved by modifying your Chrome options. I made some changes to the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

def setup_chrome_driver():
    # Create ChromeOptions instance
    options = Options()
    
    # Add various options to make the browser more stable
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Disable GPU hardware acceleration
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  # Overcome limited resource problems
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Bypass OS security model
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')  # Disable web security
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')  # Allow running insecure content
    options.add_argument('--disable-webrtc')  # Disable WebRTC
    
    # Optional: Run in headless mode if you don't need to see the browser
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    
    # Set up the service
    service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Anfield\Archive\Chromedriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
    
    try:
        # Create the driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        
        # Set page load timeout
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
        
        return driver
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error setting up ChromeDriver: {str(e)}")
        return None

# Usage example
def main():
    driver = setup_chrome_driver()
    
    if driver:
        try:
            url = 'https://shopee.co.th'
            driver.get(url)
            
            # Add a small delay to keep the browser open
            time.sleep(5)
            
            # Your scraping code here
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during execution: {str(e)}")
        
        finally:
            # Always close the driver properly
            driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I added Chrome options to disable problematic features:


Disabled GPU acceleration which may cause stability issues
Disabled WebRTC which was causing STUN server error
Added security options


Added error handling and driver cleanup
Added timeout setting to prevent infinite loading

Try the code and see if it solves the problem. If the browser still closes too quickly, try the following:

Increase the time.sleep(5) duration
Remove the driver.quit() call if you want to keep the browser open
Add a input("Press Enter to close...") before driver.quit() to control when the browser closes

Also ensure that:

Your ChromeDriver version matches your Chrome browser version
The path to ChromeDriver is correct
You have the latest version of Selenium installed (pip install --upgrade selenium).

I hope this helps

try:
# Create the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    # Set page load timeout
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    
    return driver

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error setting up ChromeDriver: {str(e)}")
    return None

I put this part it and it flagged an error on both return. what might be the cause of that?

What was the error message you got? Did you use the code the way I sent it or you added few lines to your initial code?

"message": ""return" can be used only within a function",

service = Service('C:\Anfield\Archive\Chromedriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')

remove the executable_path arg in the Service object call, instead of it write directlly your webdriver path, and check the webdriver path
